# Two while loops at one?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, irc

I'm making an IRC bot in Python. There's a `while` loop that repeats each time data is received from the IRC server. I want to have another `while` loop that runs every minute, so there's no way that I can think of to combine the loops.

Is there a way to "background" one of the loops and allow the rest of the program to keep running while it "does its thing"?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use Message Queues?

Comment: You may want to google 'python threading' here..

Comment: What you are talking about is `threads`.

Comment: consider `threading` or `multithreading`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simple example ought to get you started, In this case there are two while loops and `time.sleep(seconds)` is used to mimic some work

```
import threading
import time

def func_1():
    i = 0
    while i<5:
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1.5) # Do some work for 1.5 seconds
        print 'func_1'

def func_2():
    i = 0
    while i<5:
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.5) # Do some work for 0.5 seconds
        print 'func_2'

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func_1)
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=func_2)
thread2.start()
```

Produces:

```
func_2 #0.5 seconds elapsed
func_2 #1.0 seconds elapsed
func_1 #1.5 seconds elapsed finally func_1 :)
func_2 #1.5 threading is not mutithreading! ;)
func_2 #2.0 seconds elapsed
func_2 #2.5 seconds elapsed and since variable i is 5 func_2 is no more :(
func_1 #3.0 seconds elapsed
func_1 #4.5 seconds elapsed
func_1 #6.0 seconds elapsed
func_1 #7.5 seconds elapsed
```

## Edit:

What I meant by saying `threading is not mutithreading! ;)` is that if by any chance you think that both `func_1` and `func_2` are executed concurrently at `1.5 seconds` it is not **True** as threads run in the same memory space but if you use `multiprocessing`  they have separate memory spaces and would run concurrently

Finally, For your case you should use `threading` as its more suitable for these type of tasks

Comment: @Ant good question, I made this comment primarily for the OP *(this doesn't affect this example)*, it simply means that both `func_1` and `func_2` won't be run concurrently

Comment: So with threading they run "almost concurrently", like `print(x);print(y)`, and multithreading they actually run simultaneously? Regardless, threading works perfectly for my needs.

Comment: @LucasPhillips `threading they run "almost concurrently"` that is the case with this simple example but with more complex one's you'll see the difference BTW `threading` is what you need in this case.

Comment: @KDawG Only problem is, now when I control-C my script to kill it, it doesn't kill the thread and I have to `killall python`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @LucasPhillips generally we can't hit ctrl-c to stop a thread instead you have to do within the code *just google it*